# Sublime Text: How can I disable auto scrolling while I'm typing in the Find box?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am currently trying to write a complex regex for a huge file. Every time I type in the find input box to make a small change, Sublime scrolls me either to the top of the document or to a semi-random location (from what I can remember, it doesn't always scroll to the first match), even when there are matches where I'm already scrolled to in the file. It makes for a pretty painful workflow: I write down the line number on a piece of paper, edit my regex, and then have to "go-to" back to the line I was already at. How can I prevent this, or at the very least, does anybody know why exactly this is happening in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the `Highlight Matches` button in the `Find` and `Find and Replace` panels, and causes Sublime to show you all of the matches, highlighting one of them and outlining the remainder in a `region` to show you where they are.

[image: Location of the Highlight Matches button]

The visual appearance of the button is controlled by the theme you use, but it's always in this position in the panel (and it should have the same icon in all other find panels as well); it also has a tooltip that tells you the name.

When the search term is modified and this option is turned on, Sublime jumps to a match, though this doesn't occur if the panel opens with an existing search term already in it; in that case matches are highlighted but the view doesn't change.

The option also exists in `Incremental Find` panel as well, but turning it off there only stops other matches from being highlighted as by definition Incremental Find is for jumping to a search term incrementally as you modify it.

Comment: I think CoolOppo wants to know how to still highlight, but without jumping. The jumping makes it extraordinarily frustrating when trying to write out a complicated regex to match a bunch of text you want to replace, but you have to keep scrolling down to the target every time you input a character because sublime scrolls you to another planet